# Route to login page from shell.js in Durandal

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

I have written shell.js

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app'], function (router, app) {

return {
    router: router,

    activate: function () {
        router.map([
            { route: 'login', title: 'login', moduleId: 'viewmodels/login', nav: true }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

        return router.activate();
    }
};
```

});

and shell.html

```
<div>
<nav role="navigation">
    <div>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
            <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="page-host" data-bind="router: { transition:'entrance' }"></div>
```

My login.js is

```
define(['require', 'knockout', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'plugins/router', 'jquery'],
function (require, ko, system, app, router, $) {

var loginVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.username = ko.observable();
    self.password = ko.observable();

};

return loginVM;
```

});

and login.html is

```
<div id="openModal">
<div>

    <h4>Please login to proceed</h4>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <label for="Username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="Username" data-bind="value: userName, hasFocus: setFocus" />
        </div>
    </div>       
    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="Password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="Password" data-bind="value: password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="login" onclick="Users.login()" type="submit" data-bind="click: login, disable: session.isBusy()">Log in</button>
    </div>
    <p id="warning" class="warning">Invalid username or password !!!</p>

</div>
```

I am trying to open login page from shell. Can anyone help me with this if i am doing anything wrong as login page is not loading after shell.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No @nemesv it is showing no error and console is showing navigation occurred.

Comment: I am getting an error before shell which says scripterror in require --                 Unhandled exception at line 32, column 43 in http://localhost:63625/lib/require/require.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Script error

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the problem. Path for moduleId: 'viewmodels/login' was wrong so I made it as moduleId: 'app/viewmodels/login' and now login page is loading.